# Trouble Installing Apache from Source AIX

Tags: apache-2.4, aix

I am trying to install Apache 2.4.58 on AIX 7.2 from source, to a custom location, but make keeps running into trouble and I'm out of ideas. I know there is a script under build/aix, but we have never used it before, to my knowledge. Installing from source, this way, has never been an issue, before.

```
export CFLAGS="-m64"
export OBJECT_MODE=64

bison -pap_expr_yy --defines=/mylocation/apache/httpd-2.4.58/server/util_expr_parse.h  -o /mylocation/apache/httpd-2.4.58/server/util_expr_pa
rse.c /mylocation/apache/httpd-2.4.58/server/util_expr_parse.y
make: 1254-059 The signal code from the last command is 13.


Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.


Stop.
make: 1254-004 The error code from the last command is 1.


Stop.
```

Bison is installed and accessible, so I'm not sure why it's having trouble.

Configure parameters:
./configure \

> ```
>              --prefix=/mylocation/apache/apache2458 \
>             --enable-rewrite \
>             --enable-so \
>             --with-ssl=/mylocation/apache/openssl \
>             --enable-ssl \
>             --with-included-apr \
>             --enable-dav \
>             --enable-dav-fs \
>             --enable-auth-digest \
>             --enable-proxy \
>             --with-pcre=/mylocation/apache/pcre2/bin/pcre2-config \
>             --with-expat=/mylocation/apache/expat \
>             --cache-file=/dev/null \
>             --exec-prefix=/mylocation/apache/apache2458 \
>             --libdir=/mylocation/apache2458/lib \
>             --includedir=/mylocation/apache/apache2458/include \
>             --bindir=/mylocation/apache/apache2458/bin
> ```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Have you looked at the `config.log` file to see where the errors are?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new version of bison to compile apache 2.4.58 on AIX. The new version of bison (reference link https://github.com/akimd/bison/commit/31d4ec28bd4f7ed001bb46457ea090812c7003a7) supports pure parser syntax again, which can be obtained from Download here https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/bison/bison-3.8.2-2.aix7.1.ppc.rpm